# Spring jpa+hibernate returns empty list in @OneToMany relation

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have created 2 Entity classes:

```kotlin
@MappedSuperclass
class BaseEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    var id: Long,

    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false)
    var created: Instant,

    @Column(name = "updated", nullable = false)
    var updated: Instant,

    ) {
}
```

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
class User(
    id: Long = 0,

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    var name: String,

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    val email: String,

    created: Instant = Instant.now(),

    updated: Instant = Instant.now(),

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    var status: UserStatus = UserStatus.NOT_CONFIRMED,

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
    val auths: MutableList<UserAuth>
) : BaseEntity(id, created, updated)
```

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "auths")
class UserAuth(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    val id: Long = 0,

    @Column(name = "status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    var status: UserStatus = UserStatus.ACTIVE,

    @Column(name = "auth_info")
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    var auth: BaseAuth,

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    val user: User,


    created: Instant = Instant.now()
) : BaseAuth(created) {
}
```

When trying to get value that already had been saved in database (by UserRepository.findById(...)) it returns empty list (at User.auths). I have checked that UserAuth is connected to User when trying to find.

Also it marked for plugin all-open in gradle file:

```kotlin
allOpen {
    annotation("jakarta.persistence.Entity")
    annotation("jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass")
    annotation("jakarta.persistence.Embeddable")
}
```

I use liquidbase for migrations, and when I set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto:validate (it throws exception about schema error) - but it configured to none (as recomended in all tutorials)

I have tried to add @Join(table="auths"), @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT/SUBSELECT),@JoinColumn("user_id") and it's caused no result at all.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-6/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found reason of my problem: hibernate has first level cache. If I am trying to get an entity that I have just saved, the request to the database will not be made and the entity from the cache will be returned.